# Sorare API - Request previously sold card prices

Tags: graphql, ethereum, graphql-js, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to retrieve the price of the last sales of sorare cards for a particular player. I can't find the right argument to pass to the query to do this. I'm also looking to see if it's possible to retrieve indicators such as average card prices.

I've managed to retrieve the price of the card live at auction and the set price of the cards put up for sale on the market. However, these are only the listed prices and not the prices when the card is sold.

```
query {
  allCards (playerSlugs : "miki-yamane", rarities : super_rare owned : true) {
    nodes {
      age
      slug
      season {
        startYear
      }
      token {
        sentInLiveOffers {
          endDate
        }
        liveSingleSaleOffer {
          priceWei
        }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain it using the ownershipHistory inside the Token. Here is an example:

```
query test {
  allCards (playerSlugs : "miki-yamane", rarities : super_rare owned : true) {
    nodes {
      age
      slug
      season {
        startYear
      }
      token {
        sentInLiveOffers {
          endDate
        }
        liveSingleSaleOffer {
          status
        }
        ownershipHistory {
          from
          price{
            eur
            wei
          }
          user {
            slug
          }
        }
        
        }
      }
    }
}
```